# Setting error bar line width using \pgfplotsset

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, error-bars

In the following MWE, the lines and vertical error bars have the correct width, but not the horizontal bars. How do I set them to 'very thick'? Also, is there a way to control their length? Finally, is there a way to set the error bars to solid, while having the line being dashed?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/error bars/error bar style={very thick}}
\pgfplotsset{
  every axis plot/.append style={very thick, black},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot [dashed, mark=asterisk, error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit]
    table [x=x, y=y, y error=y-err]{%
      x y y-err
      0 0 0.5
      1 1 0.5
      2 2 0.5
      3 3 0.5
      4 4 0.5
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, using `error bar style={line width=`...`}` you can increase the thickness of the bar. With the `error mark options` you can customise the marks above and below. (See this answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19962/47927)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/error bars/error bar style={very thick}}
\pgfplotsset{
  every axis plot/.append style={very thick, black},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot [dashed, mark=asterisk, error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit,
      error bar style={line width=2pt,solid},
      error mark options={line width=1pt,mark size=4pt,rotate=90}]
    table [x=x, y=y, y error=y-err]{%
      x y y-err
      0 0 0.5
      1 1 0.5
      2 2 0.5
      3 3 0.5
      4 4 0.5
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(Edit: added note on `error mark options`, second edit: added `dashed` to plot and `solid` to `error bar style`)

Comment: This does not change the horizontal small bar above and below every point.

Comment: You can use `error mark options` to further customise the small bars at the end of the error bars.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for. Is there a way to have the line dashed while the error bar solid?

Comment: Well, add `dashed` to the `error mark options`, but I don’t know how you exactly picture the result. I guess, you have to increase the mark size to `mark size=7.5pt` in order to get a reasonable result

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you. To undash the error bars, put `solid` to the `error bar style`. The mark will then also be solid.