# Formatting error bar mark pgfplots, append to style?

Tags: pgfplots, error-bars

I am trying to increase the thickness of my error bars. I found that the stem and the marker needs to be changed individually [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19957/enlarge-error-bars-in-pgfplots). Problem with this is that using `/error bars/error mark options={*styles}` I am overwriting the defaults which gives me no marks to begin with. Trying to use `/error bars/error mark options/.append style={*styles}`, however, compiles fine but has no effect, neither does `.prefix style={*styles}`. What am I missing?

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage[]{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    error bars/error bar style={opacity=0.7,ultra thick},
    error bars/error mark options/.append style={ultra thick,red}} %does nothing
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            mystyle/.style={thick,mark=square*,only marks ,error bars/.cd, y dir = both, y explicit}
            ]
            \addplot[mystyle] table[x index={0}, y index={1},y error index={2}]
            {
            0 1 0.5
            1 1 0.5
            2 1 0.5
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

On another note, I find the design choice of the error bar styles a bit cumbersome in the first place: why is there is no high-level command to change the thickness of the vertical and horizontal portion of the error bars at the same time? But rather they need to be changed individually. Maybe a suggestion, it would be nice to combine more styles and make it the default behaviour to change both by using `error bar style`, then make the styles individually accessible via `error bar mark options` and `error bar stem options` or something of that sort. It's just my impression, but so far I have seen mostly examples, where the stem and the mark have the same thickness, so that seems to be the default for most people - myself included.

Comment: For the time being I will use `/error bars/error mark options={rotate=90, ultra thick}`.

Comment: This really isn't the place for feature requests, so your last paragraph would really be better suited in https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgfplots/issues

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks for the hint - followed your advice: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgfplots/issues/372. But also it would be nice to hear if others see it the same way, that error bar style formatting is overly involved.