# Add vertical error bar to specific points in scatter plot

Tags: pgfplots, error-bars

I have a data set of the form `x` vs. `y`.

I want to add to this data set vertical error bars only at specific coordinates

(x<sub>73</sub>,y<sub>73</sub>), (x<sub>108</sub>,y<sub>108</sub>) etc.

Otherwise my plot would be too cluttered.

I tried this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [only marks, mark size=1pt, mark options={blue}, error bars/.cd,
x dir=both, x explicit,
y dir=both, y explicit,
error mark options={
      rotate=90,
      red,
      mark size=3pt,
%      line width=1pt
    }
] table [y error=error] {
x   y   error
1 8 0
2 5 0
3 7 2 % <--This coordinate should have error bar
4 6 0
5 7 0
6 9 0
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: wrong representation of error bats]

If you don't specify any `error mark options` as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19962/180429), you get a seemingly desired result.

But I want the error marks to be a bit longer than the default, and by extending it I also extend the zero's error's marks.

How to avoid that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good answer would require to know how your data file really looks like and what your real purpose is. So here I present three solutions in one.

1. You can modify the data file to your needs.
   Replace all `error` values with `NaN` where you don't want to show an error bar. Then you can stick with `y error=error`.
2. You want to show an error bar every N bars.
   Then all data points could have listed there real error values and you use `y error expr={mod(\coordindex,2) != 0 ? NaN : \thisrow{error}}`. Adapt the `2` to your needs.
3. The data file has real error values of 0 but you don't want to show an error bar on that data points. Then use `error expr={\thisrow{error} == 0 ? NaN : \thisrow{error}}`

```
% used PGFPlots v1.18.1
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot [
            only marks,
            mark size=1pt,
            mark options={blue},
            error bars/.cd,
                y dir=both, y explicit,
                error mark options={
                    rotate=90,
                    red,
                    mark size=3pt,
                }
        ] table [
%            y error=error,
            y error expr={mod(\coordindex,2) != 0 ? NaN : \thisrow{error}},
%            y error expr={\thisrow{error} == 0 ? NaN : \thisrow{error}},
        ] {
            x   y   error
            1   8   0
            2   5   0
            3   7   2
            4   6   NaN
            5   7   NaN
            6   9   NaN
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: I am going to stick with the `NaN` solution. Should have thought about it by my self. Thanks a lot!